# Trim More than two trailing Zeros in BigDecimal

Tags: java, bigdecimal

What would be a good way to trim more than two trailing zeros for a BigDecimal

So 1.2200 would print 1.22 and 1.0000 would print 1.00

Edit **As well as to return 1.222200 as
1.2222 and 1.220000001 as 1.220000001 etc. So disregarding first two zeros I want to trim any incoming 0s and not trim non-zero values**

One way could be to multiply, then apply the built in trim trailing zeros and then divide by 100. It could be problematic with corner cases  but the values in my problem are currency based and would never exceed the bounds set by Java (or else it means my software is dealing with bids which are in gazzilions of dollars)

The ugly solution is as folows

```
System.out.println(((new BigDecimal("1.230223000")
                                 .multiply(new BigDecimal("100.0"))
                                 .stripTrailingZeros()).divide(new BigDecimal("100.0"))));
```

Comment: note that your new requirements conflict with your original ones: how can `1.230223000` be turned into `1.230223`, but `1.0000` should print `1.00`?

Comment: no they don't Joachim. read again. I want to ignore the first two zeros after decimal for trimming. And the input will always be of atleast x.xx type

Comment: yep, I realized that after I posted my comment. Does my (updated) answer help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check this,

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class DecimalFormatExample
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
  double amount = 2192.015;
  NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
  System.out.println("The Decimal Value is:"+formatter.format(amount));
  }
}
```

Comment: This will truncate `new BigDecimal("1.234")` which (according to the new requirements) should be printed in full.

Answer (score 14):

**Update**: Having those mixed requirements (i.e. at least 2 digits after the decimal point should be displayed, but as many as necessary) is not trivially implemented, but you can come close:

Combine `stripTrailingZeros()` with `DecimalFormat` to get the desired behaviour (or close to it):

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00########")
String formatted = df.format(bigDecimal.stripTrailingZeros())
```

This will format any `BigDecimal` value with at least 2 digits after the decimal point and up to 10 digits after the decimal point, if it improves the precision.

`BigDecimal` values with *more* than 10 digits after the decimal point will still be cut off:

```
      input      |  output
-----------------+----------
 1.20000         | 1.20
 1.23000         | 1.23
 1.2301          | 1.2301
 1.230001000     | 1.230001
 1.2300000000001 | 1.23
```

---

*Original answer:*

If you always want to have exactly 2 digits after the comma and know that you won't lose precision this way, then you can call [`setScale(2, RoundingMode.UNNECESSARY)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale%28int,%20java.math.RoundingMode%29):

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal("1.23000").setScale(2, RoundingMode.UNNECESSARY));
```

This code will print `1.23`. Note that this will throw an [`ArithmeticException`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ArithmeticException.html) when rounding would be necessary (i.e. anything after the first 2 digits is not zero).

If your values can have a higher precision and you want to apply some rounding, simply replace `RoundingMode.UNNECESSARY` with [the appropriate value](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html):

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal("1.2301").setScale(2, RoundingMode.CEILING));
```

This will print `1.24`.

If you don't know the exact number of digits but want as few as possible (i.e. you want the smallest possible `scale` for your `BigDecimal`) then calling [`stripTrailingZeros()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#stripTrailingZeros%28%29) will do exactly what you want:

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal("1.230001000").stripTrailingZeros();
```

This will print `1.230001`.

Comment: Note: my answer assumes you need the *value*. If you *only* want to format how the value is displayed, then the answer by @Max is more appropriate.

Comment: I do need the value, and I also want it to work for the following case  BigDecimal 1.230002000000 returns BigDecimal 1.230002

Comment: @geoaxis: I've updated my answer for these changed requirements.

Answer (score 1):

This method will give you the result you want (monetary round):
(what is String because it's better for BigDecimal see documentation)

```
public static float roundUp(String what, int howmuch) throws Exception{

    try {
        return (new BigDecimal(what).setScale(howmuch, BigDecimal.ROUND_UP)).floatValue();
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        throw new Exception("BigDecimal cannot parse value : " + what, nfe);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's for displaying purposes use:

```
BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal("1.2200");
NumberFormat n = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
String s = n.format(d.doubleValue());
```

Answer (score 0):

For outputting as `String`, use `DecimalFormat`.

Otherwise, use this:

```
public static BigDecimal stripToMinimumScale(BigDecimal value, 
                                             final int minimumScale) {
  if (value.scale() == minimumScale) // Already correct scale
    return value;
  else {
    value = value.stripTrailingZeros();
    return (value.scale() < minimumScale) ?  
        value.setScale(minimumScale) : // Too few decimals, needs zero pad
        value; // Do not round any significant digits
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal("59.0000");
String d1 = new DecimalFormat().format(d);
System.out.println("d1 is " + d1);
```

Comment: this answer was already posted, and does not fall into the scope of "fastest gun in the west"