# Issue with bigdecimal multiply operation

Tags: java, javascript

I have a jsf project with there are some javascript masks for percentual values. The one i'm using is this:

```
jQuery('.mascaraDescontos, .maskValor-gris').priceFormat({
        prefix : '',
        limit : 5,
        centsLimit : 2,
        centsSeparator : ',',
        thousandsSeparator : ''
    });
```

There is a functionality which calculate some discounts involving some of these percentual values.

Let's say that i put these two values:

```
5,00
AND
2,50
```

One thing i do with these values is to divide them by 100:

```
value.divide(new BigDecimal(100));
```

Which gives to me these values as result:

```
0.05
and
0.025
```

The second operation i do is to multiply these same values again by 100

```
value.multiply(new BigDecimal(100));
```

Which gives me:

```
5.00
and
2.500 --- this extra zero here...
```

When the same value goes to the page, the javascript mask make it appear as 25.00...

What am i missing here? Is it a javascript issue? Or a bigdecimal issue?

Comment: @fge Does `BigDecimal` not warrant `java`?

Comment: Try to use answer from here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6176064/2782135

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00########")
    String formatted = df.format(bigDecimal.stripTrailingZeros())

Comment: Why not work with an appropriate scale and a rounding mode of your interest such as `value=value.multiply(new BigDecimal(100)).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);`? (This has whatsoever nothing to do JSF).

Comment: @Tiny when i set the scale, my number turns to 2.50000....

Comment: That precisely cannot be envisioned without looking into the code you attempted. How do you set the scale?